# not work my first react-native app run-android ***

Tags: react-native

my system information :

System:

```
OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7360U CPU @ 2.30GHz
Memory: 1.84 GB / 8.00 GB
Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
```

Binaries:

```
Node: 12.16.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.4 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 6.13.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
```

SDKs:

```
iOS SDK:
  Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
```

IDEs:

```
Android Studio: 3.6 AI-192.7142.36.36.6241897
Xcode: 11.3.1/11C505 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
```

npmPackages:

```
react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5
```

my terminal errors , screen shot :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

If ANDROID_HOME is not defined, the value in ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is used.

I quote from react-native offical documentation:

> Add the following lines to your $HOME/.bash_profile or $HOME/.bashrc config file:

```sh
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

> Type source $HOME/.bash_profile to load the config into your current shell. Verify that ANDROID_HOME has been added to your path by running echo $PATH.

See: https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Create new file in your project android/local.properties. 
Add Android SDK path in that file like this:
 `sdk.dir = /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk` 
*Where USERNAME is your OSX username*. 



Hope this helps.